# User links and edit rejection reasons in reviews are harder to read in the new UI; please increase their contrast ratio

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, accessibility

I've been finding some of the text in the new review UI a bit hard to read. The blue background of the UI tends to greatly decrease the contrast of the text, making it hard to read.

In particular, it seems like the text of the user links [only use a contrast ratio of 3.3:1](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=4E82C2&bcolor=E1ECF4), and the text of suggested edit rejections are even worse with a contrast ratio of [only 2.4:1](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=9199A1&bcolor=E1ECF4). Neither of these ratios are compliant with the accessibility standards for non-large text, and the latter fails to even meet the requirement for large text.

[image]

Can the contrast ratios of these please be increased, so they're easier for others to read and don't violate accessibility standards?

(As a side note, the new Developer Tools in modern Microsoft Edge have an automatic contrast ratio checker, which can be used to easily check if the ratio is large enough.)

Comment: Off-note: Edge has nothing to do with the ratio checker per se, it is the Chromium engine we have to thank for it (and it is also obviously available in Chrome).

Comment: @OlegValter That's super cool! I didn't know that existed. Found [some details on how to see it](https://webaim.org/articles/contrast/devtools) for those curious.

Comment: @zcoop98 - yeah, the contrast checker is cool :) I also like the accessibility tree rendering (also in the experimental features). I wish those would be more prominently featured and relegated to the depths of "advanced" options.