# Has the staff and mod labels color code changed?

Tags: support, bug, design, moderators, display-names

As per the post: [New Staff and Mod Labels on site metas and Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367899/312043), the moderator and staff label's color could be the below:

> [image]

But today I see the label's color is changed as below:

> [image]

So, is it a bug or any change in the label's color code?

Comment: [This request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367912/349058) asking for it has been marked [status-completed]. So it is intentional.

Comment: See the “Update” in the linked post.