# Staff members no longer have Staff labels on their main sites profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, stack-exchange-team

Here's what the username line looks like on RPG main

[image]

And meta (sorry @Slate, I just happened to spot it on your profile):

[image]

From a brief investigation, this appears to affect all staff and consistently across other main/meta sites. For staff without diamonds there is no indication on their profile page that they're staff. In fact, they seem to include exactly the opposite.

This appears to be a regression of [Employee profiles are now marked with a “Staff” indicator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331654/681403), presumably due to one (or both) of the recent changes around [staff labels](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367899/681403) and [user profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368285/681403), however neither of those list any indication these staff labels would be going away.

In addition, the announcement says:

> The new mod badges will not yet be included on Main sites (or anywhere on Chat or the main StackExchange.com site) where for the time being, the good old unaddorned mod diamond will live on. And there are no plans to show staff labels on Main sites **aside from the profile page**.

The part on bold is no longer true, hence likely a bug.

Comment: I've clarified the actual bug which affects only profile pages, it wasn't clear at first and I thought you mean it doesn't show in other places on main sites.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is now fixed (and along with it a regression issue that stopped showing staff labels entirely on the mobile profile).

> Main site user page
> Are they staff or not? Tell me!
> Staff label returned

Comment: Not only have the staff labels returned, the haikus have returned as well :)

Comment: Any bug you can see? Not at all you should ever worry! Yaakov corrected it already...

Comment: The Moderator markers on profiles are in the bright blue while the Staff markers are in the pale orange. :)