# The new Meta labels for Mod and Staff cover descenders

Tags: discussion, bug

The height of new labels takes them all the way up to the above baseline thus covering the [desenders](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender)

[image: q]

Is this intentional?

(And apologies for the image and the lack of a freehand circle.)

Comment: This is already mentioned [under the original post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367938) and is marked [status-review]