# Can the staff label resemble the mod label?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Recently the mod label got a darker coloured border, as to better set it apart from the blue background that is used on a usercard when one is the OP. As was requested in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368532/361484).

This leaves a bit of a discrepancy between the staff and mod labels, with one having a darker border than the other.

[image: Screenshot of a comment by Yaakov Ellis who has both a staff and a mod badge. The mod badge has a darker border than the staff badge comparatively.]

Looking at the CSS there is a small difference. Both border colours use a value of `[colour]-200`, but the backgrounds use a value of `[colour]-100` for the orange colour, and the blue uses `[colour]-075`. For the orange colour a value of `orange-075` doesn't exist, but this could explain the difference in contrast. Increasing the border colour of the orange from `-200` to `-300` looks better I think.

Comment: Don't forget: How is the result to [appear on the profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeTTb.jpg) as a result of making this change?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Coincidentally, we had this same discussion internally today and I came to the same conclusion that you did. We've tweaked this [upstream](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/748) in our Stacks design library. This will land network-wide soon (tomorrow-ish), so I'm going to go ahead and mark as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) instead of [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) so I don't forget to come back and edit this post later.

Comment: Looks like it is pushed by now. Looks great!