# The /help/staff page inconsistently uses "label", "marker", and "tag" to describe what denotes staff

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center, wording, user-labels

In [/help/staff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/staff), this is mentioned:

> **How can I identify a staff member?**
>
> Staff fall into one of two categories, with different indicators:
>
> - General staff - these staff members represent the bulk of our employees. They are regular users for the most part. If you see one of them on our meta sites, they will have a staff ***label*** on their posts and comments and a staff ***marker*** on their meta profile pages.
> - Diamond staff - a small subset of our staff - generally the developers, engineers, and community team members - need special access to moderation tools and content. They are more visible and bear a diamond next to their username, just like our [elected site moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators). They have both "Moderator" and "Staff" ***tags*** on their profiles.

What's the difference between label, marker and tag? If all mean the same thing, can we use a consistent term instead of multiple terms in the help center article?

P.S. In [Ask Ubuntu's /help/staff](https://askubuntu.com/help/staff), I noticed that the "*elected site moderators*" hyperlink links to [MSE/help/site-moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators). Shouldn't the hyperlink link to [AU/help/site-moderators](https://askubuntu.com/help/site-moderators)?

Comment: This is a feature request to change wording in help center about user labels of Stack Exchange team aka staff. Please don't remove those tags, they are all relevant.

Comment: Regarding your "P.S.": You are indeed correct. For some reason, that link uses an absolute URL pointing to the `/help/site-moderators` page on MSE specifically, rather than being a relative link pointing to the corresponding page on the same site. (So no matter what site you view the `/help/staff` page from, that link will point to an MSE Help Center page.)

Comment: @V2Blast Was my flag the reason of you adding the status-review tag? But it was declined... so I am confused.

Comment: @RandomPerson: Indirectly – I was pinged by the mods, which reminded me to make this change since it was a simple one. (I added the tag because I was already going to work on it, so that my team could track my work internally.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've now fixed the issues noted in your post (both the inconsistent terminology, and the absolute link mentioned in the last line of your post). I also added some more detail to each bullet point.

The relevant section of the Help Center page ["Who are the staff, and what is their role here?"](/help/staff) (located at `/help/staff` on each site) now reads:

> Staff fall into one of two categories, with different indicators:
>
> - General staff: These staff members represent the bulk of our employees. They are regular users for the most part. If you see one of them on our meta sites, a "Staff" label will be shown next to their username on their posts and comments. They also have a "Staff" label on their profile page on both meta and non-meta sites.
> - Diamond staff: A small subset of our staff – generally the developers, engineers, and community team members – need special access to moderation tools and content. They are more visible and bear a diamond (♦) next to their username, just like our [elected site moderators](/help/site-moderators); on meta sites, both the "Staff" and "♦ Mod" labels will appear by their username. In addition, both the "Staff" and "♦ Moderator" labels will be shown on their profile page on both meta and non-meta sites.

I chose to keep the initial reference to "indicators", since it's inclusive of both user labels (like "Staff"/"Moderator") and other indicators (like the diamond on its own).

Comment: Thank you for editing the article V2Blast!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, they all mean the same.

Yes, it should be changed to be consistent.

**However**, which is the best word to use? This I don't know.

Personally, I'd go with a *fourth* word that was used in the [original announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331654/employee-profiles-are-now-marked-with-a-staff-indicator): **indicator**.

*Staff indicator* means something that indicates this user is a staff member.

So would like to see all mentions of label/marker/tag in that context changed to indicator.

Comment: Well, indicator and labels are different I suppose. Indicators are there in profile page and labels are there next to username in comments and posts?  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367899

Comment: @RandomPerson no, they are all the same thing, just using different words every time, which is indeed confusing. It's more than just help center, it's how staff themselves refer to it.

Comment: @RandomPerson the *words* don't meant that. An indicator is just something that *indicates*. A label is very similar semantically as it is used to distinguish something. They *might* have separate domain-specific meaning attached to them but I'm not aware of that being the case. The post you link to mentions "*there are no plans to show staff labels on Main sites aside from the profile page*" putting the word "label" within the context of "profile". And doesn't mention "indicator" at all. I'm more inclined to believe there is no domain-specific language here *yet*, just plain English.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's any fixed/"official" term for this... "Label" is probably what we (and the community) use most consistently overall. But "indicator" and "marker" aren't any less correct; they're just being used in their regular English meanings here (i.e. as something that marks/indicates the fact that those users are staff).

Comment: @V2Blast thanks. I'd also go with "label", just better have it consistent, at least in official places like help center. But since you didn't even throw this into the review queue, guess it's not going to happen?

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard what do you mean by "review queue" in the context? You mean [tag:status-review]?

Comment: @RandomPerson oops yes, on second reading it's confusing indeed. Stack Exchange developers have internal list of things to fix/add, and any question here tagged as status-review automatically enters this list. :)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard: I figured I'd wait for more feedback to come in first, and then the mods (or I) could add the tag if they felt appropriate. Me not personally adding the tag to a post immediately after it's made doesn't mean it won't get done at some point...

Answer (score 6):

According to the [original announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331654/employee-profiles-are-now-marked-with-a-staff-indicator), these things are called labels.

There are a few other words used in the entire Q&A there, but for example [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331654/employee-profiles-are-now-marked-with-a-staff-indicator#comment1083267_331655) by [Yaakov Ellis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/51/yaakov-ellis) makes it clear that it is a label.

> The mobile profile now shows the **staff label** for Stack Overflow employees. Thanks for the request.

<sub><sup><sub>Emphasis mine</sub></sup></sub>

And so does [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331654/employee-profiles-are-now-marked-with-a-staff-indicator#comment1081878_331659) by [Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija):

> This doesn't really relate to **the label**. There's no change in any policy regarding diamonds.

<sub><sup><sub>Emphasis mine</sub></sup></sub>